# OpenGlES2.0 Texture issue

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to opengl, i am trying to apply texture to the 3D figure ,but i am getting glGetUniformLocation: glError 1282 error,please help me with this, i searched online but couldn't rectify it.would be happy if someone explains the issue also.

MY Shaders:

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "attribute vec2 texCoord;" +
                "varying vec2 texCoordOut;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "  texCoordOut = texCoord;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 texColor"+
                "varying vec2 texCoordOut;" +
                "uniform sampler2D Texture;" +
                "void main() {" +
                " texColor = texture2D(Texture, texCoordOut);" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texColor;" +
                "}";
```

Draw method:

```
public void draw1(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    vsTextureCoord = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "texCoord");
    fsTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Texture");
    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vsTextureCoord, COORDS_PER_TEXTURE,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TextureStride, texBuffer);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(fsTexture, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tablelamp21NumVerts);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);

}
```

LoadTexture:

```
public void loadGLTexture(Context context) {
    GLES20.glGenTextures(4, textures, 0);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        // Create a bitmap
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceIds[i]);
        //...and bind it to our array
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
        //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        //Clean up
        bitmap = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't even be able to compile the shaders in the first place.

In the fragment shader, you've declared 
Sampler2D as variable **Texture**, but you're using **u_texture** to sample it.
Use same variable name in both places, which should also be same as

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "attribute vec2 texCoord;" +
            "varying vec2 texCoordOut;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
            "  texCoordOut = texCoord;" +
            "}";


private final String fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 texcColor"+
            "varying vec2 texCoordOut;" +
            "uniform sampler2D u_texture;" +
            "void main() {" +
            " texColor = texture2D(u_texture, texCoordOut);" +
            "  gl_FragColor = texColor;" +
            "}";
```

And in the GLES code,

```
 fsTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_texture");
```

Comment: thank you for pointing it out,fixed it, but still getting the same error.

Comment: texcColor ?? Hope you have fixed all the typos in the shaders.

Comment: sorry,that is a typing error when i was writing the question,it is perfect in my code.after digging i found that my glCreateProgram() is returning 0 i.e it is failing to create a program,i am calling glCreateProgram() in the constructor of triangle class,the Initialization of triangle class object is done in onSurfaceCreated().

Comment: I suggest, you check compilation status of the fragment shader.
`vec4 texColor` should NOT be a uniform. It just has to be a local variable.